# MessageBox.Show not working on button click

Tags: c#, messagebox

everybody. :)

Totally new to C# right now, so I apologize for the probable idiocy of this question. :P I've done quite a bit of searching over the past couple of hours and not been able to find anything that has solved my issue, unfortunately.

I've been running through some basic C# guides, and I'm going through the creation of a simple Windows Form Application with a button that, when clicked, displays a MessageBox with a short phrase in it. Oddly, though, when I debug the app and click the button, nothing happens. In my searches, I've seen many situations where people have the MessageBox show with no text; in this situation, however, absolutely nothing is happening. It acts as though there is no action being applied whatsoever.

I'm using VSC# 2010 Express. I tried this with fresh projects and installs on both my Windows 7 machine and my XP machine, same results on both.

Thanks for your help! Code pasted below.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Here's a message??");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you wired the button1_click event handler to the Click event of your button?

Comment: I think your event handler is not hooked up to your buttons click event. Look at the designer for the button and take a look at the events it has and hook your handler with the click event simply bye choosing it. Or you could double click the button on the designer and paste your show messagebox code into the new event handler

Comment: how did you created button1_click event handler? Copied from tutorial? If so just **double click button1 in form designer** and add message box in created event handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hook button1_click Event Handler to the Click Event of your Button

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        button1.Click += new EventHandler(button1_Click); 
        //add above line
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Here's a message??");
    }
```

What was happening was that you just wrote your event coding but there was no call for it.

With this line `button1.Click += new EventHandler(button1_Click);` when click happens it will execute `private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)` function.

Comment: `new DontRememberWhatcomeshere(button1_Click)` change to `button1_Click`

Comment: DontRememberWhatcomeshere that's the best i read so far :D:D LOL :D

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal no don't change it was so funny. :D:D

Comment: Excellent! This was exactly what I needed. Thanks also for the explanation of what was going on; that really does help!! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You probably haven't hooked up your actual button to this event handler. In the designer select the button, and in the properties window click the little icon of a ligtning bolt. Find the `Click` event and drop down the selection and select `button1_Click`.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the event handler is not registered for the click event.

Try changing your code like this :

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    button_1.Click += new EventHandler(button_1_Click);
}
```

Or something along these lines...

Answer (score 0):

Seems event binding for button is not done properly. Please double click on button that is there in the designer, it will create a event like this. Now you put your message code there and hope it will work.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Here's a message??");
        }
```

Comment: This also worked, which is really interesting to me! It seems that having the `button_1.Click += new EventHandler(button_1_Click);` line works regardless of whether it's placed in Form1.cs or Form1.Designer.cs.